# 'undefined' is undefined in ios5

Tags: javascript, safari, ios5

I upgraded to ios5 and my little app o longer works. I am getting a really nebulous error 
JavaScript error undefined type error 'undefined' is not an object
The problem is, I don't have a variable called undefined.
I am also getting a cache manifest error
Application cach manifest has an incorrect Mime type image/png
Which I believe is a result of my script converting an svg canvas to a png (it worked in its 4). Any help with this weird, nebulous undefined error would help. I tried using alerts to try and see what variable is being declared undefined, but the error simply states undefined is not an object and gives no variable name or even what line of code the error appears on.

Code below

Can not properly format code from iPad despite using menu buttons, please try the link below and view source.

You can view it here lesserslavery.org/ice.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined-error means you are trying to access a variable in an object way, even though the object is not defined. Probably you are assuming somewhere that certain element was assigned for the variable, which it wasn't.

For the mime type question, your server probably is sending wrong mime type with the file defined in cache.manifest. Check possible explanation here: [Debugging html5 offline web apps](http://www.fuckyeahtml5.com/2011/06/debugging-html5s-offline-web-apps/)